# Command Output Applet Question

Tags: applet

When using the stock [Command Output Applet](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/command-runner-applet/) how can I display a command output plus a string. For example echo date -u +%R`" UTC" outputs 12:59 UTC as expected from terminal but does not work properly in applet. First image shows what I wanted minus the UTC label.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know anything about the applet you're referencing, but just wanted to point out that there's no need to use echo + command substitution here - you can add text directly to the `date` format string i.e. `date '+%R UTC'` (although I suspect you should really be using `date '%R %Z'` rather than assuming the timezone).

Comment: I added some pics